# How to write regex to match password with rules

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I'm trying to write regex to match password with following rule

Minimum length - 8 characters, if it includes a number and a lowercase letter OR 15 characters with any combination of characters

Here's my regex

`^(?=.*\d[a-z]).{8,}|([a-zA-Z0-9]{15,})$`

Expected result: 
`2232ddds` - correct
`ddds2222` - correct

Actual result:
`2232ddds` - correct
`ddds2222` - incorrect

Could you help me to find a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are two:

- The anchors only affect the alternatives they stand next to
- The `(?=.*\d[a-z])` lookahead requires a digit and a lowercase to appear in this order only, if there is a letter and then a digit, it won't work.

You may use

```
/^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,})$/
  ^^^|-----------------|     ^                ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZSXWf/1).

If you want to make it more efficient and follow best practices use

```
/^(?:(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]).{8,}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,})$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - a  non-capturing group start

  - `(?=\D*\d)` - at least 1 digit
  - `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - at least 1 lowercase letter
  - `.{8,}` - any 8 or more chars other than line break chars
- `|` - or

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,}` - 15 or more alphanumeric chars only
- `)` - end of non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here a few options you can choose to build your regex:

String contains at least one:

- Lower case `(?=.*[a-z])`
- Upper case `(?=.*[A-Z])`
- Numbers `(?=.*\d)`
- Symbols `(?=.[!@#\$%\^&])`

Minimal characters of string: `(?=.{8,})`

Your regex would be: `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.{8,})|(?=.{15,})`

Hope this helps!